# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers'

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

When I am trying this import:

```
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
```

I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[121], line 1
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers'
```

I tried to use another library, scikeras.wrappers, but when I want to fit I get another error

```
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

keras_sk_reg = KerasRegressor(model=ann_model)
param_grid = {
    'number_of_hidden_layers' : [1, 3, 5],
    'number_of_neurons' : [16, 32, 64],
    'lr' : [0.001, 0.01, 0.1]
keras_sk_reg_gs = GridSearchCV(keras_sk_reg, param_grid=param_grid)
keras_sk_reg_gs.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=10, callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5)])
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[116], line 1
----> 1 keras_sk_reg_gs.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=10, callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5)])

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1151, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1144     estimator._validate_params()
   1146 with config_context(
   1147     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1148         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1149     )
   1150 ):
-> 1151     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:898, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    892     results = self._format_results(
    893         all_candidate_params, n_splits, all_out, all_more_results
    894     )
    896     return results
--> 898 self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    900 # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable
    901 # self.scoring the return type is only known after calling
    902 first_test_score = all_out[0]["test_scores"]

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:1419, in GridSearchCV._run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1417 def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1418     """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1419     evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:845, in BaseSearchCV.fit.<locals>.evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    837 if self.verbose > 0:
    838     print(
    839         "Fitting {0} folds for each of {1} candidates,"
    840         " totalling {2} fits".format(
    841             n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits
    842         )
    843     )
--> 845 out = parallel(
    846     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    847         clone(base_estimator),
    848         X,
    849         y,
    850         train=train,
    851         test=test,
    852         parameters=parameters,
    853         split_progress=(split_idx, n_splits),
    854         candidate_progress=(cand_idx, n_candidates),
    855         **fit_and_score_kwargs,
    856     )
    857     for (cand_idx, parameters), (split_idx, (train, test)) in product(
    858         enumerate(candidate_params), enumerate(cv.split(X, y, groups))
    859     )
    860 )
    862 if len(out) < 1:
    863     raise ValueError(
    864         "No fits were performed. "
    865         "Was the CV iterator empty? "
    866         "Were there no candidates?"
    867     )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py:65, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
     60 config = get_config()
     61 iterable_with_config = (
     62     (_with_config(delayed_func, config), args, kwargs)
     63     for delayed_func, args, kwargs in iterable
     64 )
---> 65 return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:1085, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   1076 try:
   1077     # Only set self._iterating to True if at least a batch
   1078     # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
   (...)
   1082     # was very quick and its callback already dispatched all the
   1083     # remaining jobs.
   1084     self._iterating = False
-> 1085     if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1086         self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1088     while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:901, in Parallel.dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    899     return False
    900 else:
--> 901     self._dispatch(tasks)
    902     return True

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:819, in Parallel._dispatch(self, batch)
    817 with self._lock:
    818     job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 819     job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    820     # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    821     # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to
    822     # grow. To ensure correct results ordering, .insert is
    823     # used (rather than .append) in the following line
    824     self._jobs.insert(job_idx, job)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py:208, in SequentialBackend.apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206 def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207     """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208     result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209     if callback:
    210         callback(result)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py:597, in ImmediateResult.__init__(self, batch)
    594 def __init__(self, batch):
    595     # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    596     # arguments in memory
--> 597     self.results = batch()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:288, in BatchedCalls.__call__(self)
    284 def __call__(self):
    285     # Set the default nested backend to self._backend but do not set the
    286     # change the default number of processes to -1
    287     with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 288         return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    289                 for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:288, in <listcomp>(.0)
    284 def __call__(self):
    285     # Set the default nested backend to self._backend but do not set the
    286     # change the default number of processes to -1
    287     with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 288         return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    289                 for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py:127, in _FuncWrapper.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    125     config = {}
    126 with config_context(**config):
--> 127     return self.function(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:720, in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, split_progress, candidate_progress, error_score)
    717     for k, v in parameters.items():
    718         cloned_parameters[k] = clone(v, safe=False)
--> 720     estimator = estimator.set_params(**cloned_parameters)
    722 start_time = time.time()
    724 X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py:1165, in BaseWrapper.set_params(self, **params)
   1161             super().set_params(**{param: value})
   1162         except ValueError:
   1163             # Give a SciKeras specific user message to aid
   1164             # in moving from the Keras wrappers
-> 1165             raise ValueError(
   1166                 f"Invalid parameter {param} for estimator {self.__name__}."
   1167                 "\nThis issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter"
   1168                 f" in the {self.__name__} constructor:"
   1169                 f"\n`{self.__name__}({param}={value})`"
   1170                 "\nCheck the list of available parameters with"
   1171                 " `estimator.get_params().keys()`"
   1172             ) from None
   1173 return self

ValueError: Invalid parameter lr for estimator KerasRegressor.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(lr=0.001)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`
```